# HubSpot CLI Error: [ERROR] A RequestError has occurred. Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND raw.githubusercontent.com

Tags: command-line-interface, hubspot

When I tried to run the following command

`hs create template basic-page`

it gives me this error

```
[ERROR] A RequestError has occurred. Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Solution how to fix the error, is there any dependent needs to install?